# Formula Field, Date Field, how do i get the date for 'the sunday before' a given date?

Tags: apex, formula-field

I have a date field, let's say datex__c. i need a formula field that takes datex__c and returns me the date of the sunday before datex__c. any ideas?

thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested code but the formula below should subtract the correct number of days from `datex__c`

```
datex__c - (MOD(datex__c - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7) + 1)
```

It is based on the **Finding and Displaying the Day of the Week From a Date** example from the [Common Date Formula examples](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&language=en_US#getting-DoW-from-date)